# Stopped custom services controlled by systemd do not appear in systemctl list-units --full --all

Tags: systemd

We have developed custom services in ubuntu and they are installed and enabled for systemd.

When these custom services are stopped using systemctl stop , the stopped services do not appear in "systemctl list-units --full --all" CLI. The service start works well and that appears in list-units output.

I need to be able to list loaded but stopped units. Please note "systemctl list-unit-files --full --all" does show the custom services. But that CLI is meant only for "enabled" service and not "loaded" so not useful for us.

Other default services such sshd/postfix etc when stopped do appear the list-units listing.

Any clues/suggestion for me to figure out what is going wrong?

My ubuntu and systemd version are as below. Service template is also given below

Systemd Details

```
systemd --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

Ubuntu Version

```
   cat /etc/os-release
   NAME="Ubuntu"
   VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
   ID=ubuntu
   ID_LIKE=debian
   PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
   VERSION_ID="16.04"
   HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
   SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
   VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
   UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Service template

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Service
Requires=dependent_1.service dependent_2.service custom_init.service
Wants=networking.service
After=custom_init2.service custom2.service
OnFailure=abnormal_process_notifier@custom.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/foo/bar/libexec/custom_service_exe
ExecStartPost=/opt/foo/bar/libexec/notify_state_change %p 1
ExecStopPost=/opt/foo/bar/libexec/notify_state_change %p 0

ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=450
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
RequiredBy=custom.target
```

Comment: `list-units` shows all loaded units where `list-units-files` shows all installed units on the system. Did you do `systemctl daemon-reload` after installing your service file?

Comment: there is a typo in your comment: it's "list-unit-files" ;-)